# TotoiseHG: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: git, github, mercurial, tortoisehg, hg-git

I wanted to push a project from from **TortoiseHg** to **GitHub**. I know that, TortoiseHg is a front-end to the Mercurial distributed version control system; where GitHub works with Git. But I love to use TortoiseHg (instead of TortoiseGit or GitGui), and want to keep my project in GitHub.

So, I configured TortoiseHg (*File>Settings>Extensions>hggit*) and was able to push a test project to GitHub (following [this](http://www.ryadel.com/en/using-github-with-mercurial-and-tortoisehg/) wonderful blog). But later when I tried to push a **C# MVC** project with it, situation changed.
It nicely starts pushing, then asks for authentication, & then shows this error-

[image: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]

Here is what shown in the log-

> ```
> % hg push git+https://github.com/MinhasKamal/MVCPracticeWork
> pushing to git+https://github.com/MinhasKamal/MVCPracticeWork
> http authorization required for https://github.com/MinhasKamal/MVCPracticeWork/info/refs
> realm: GitHub
> searching for changes
> adding objects
> URLError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> [command returned code 255 Thu Feb 04 16:17:02 2016]
> ```

I don't understand- why this error is happening. Is this a problem of GitHub or TortoiseHG, or I did something wrong? How it can be solved?

---

**Edit 1:** I am able to push to the repository but **only by 'not adding' some specific directories to my repository**. Is it any file type or name that is making this error?

---

**Edit 2:** The problem again happened with me, this time with a Java project. Everything was fine, till I added a **.jar* file in the repository. I made a commit, but when I tried to push it to the GitHub, TortoiseHg showed me the same message. I removed the **.jar*, committed, and tried to push again, but couldn't.

Now, I did again that I did before (Edit 1)- I pulled the whole repository from GitHub to another folder, replaced changed files from the current repository at my PC (did not add the **.jar*), committed, and pushed; I was successful this time. So, this time the **jar* file was not added to the version control database, that is why it worked.

Comment: Your version of THG and hg-git have to be shown, maybe they are ancient as mammoth's bullshit

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/6554921/6309)

Comment: @VonC I am not sure, may be I am not behind any proxy.

Comment: I don't think you are actually, since you can push without certain files

Comment: What version of TortoiseHg, and git are you using?

Comment: @VonC TortoiseHg version is- *3.6.3*, Mercurial- *3.6.3*, Qt- *4.8.6*. I am pushing Mercurial repository to GitHub using an add-in **hg-git**. So, git version should be the latest.

Comment: OK. I was reading http://support.hglabhq.com/discussions/problems/396-when-pushing-files-over-some-20mb-i-get-abort-error-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host, but that was 3 years ago.

Comment: @VonC And my file size was only 380kb.

Comment: Can you check if you have a mercurial.ini in your user directory (%USERPROFILE% if you are on Windows) as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10298166/6309? (or http://stackoverflow.com/a/6554938/6309)

Comment: @VonC Yes, I have. Should I delete it? Here is the content-  [extensions] \n
hggit = \n
eol= \n
[ui] \n
username=MinhasKamal <minhaskamal024@gmail.com> \n


[auth] \n
github.com.prefix = github.com \n
github.com.username = MinhasKamal \n

Comment: OK, so no proxy entry there, you can leave it as is.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Does your TortoiseHG uses IIS in any way? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17372530/6309)

Comment: @VonC I am on Windows. I have VisualStudio in my PC, but IIS was not running. So, It should not be used by TSVN.

Comment: Do you have git in your %PATH%? What `git --version` returns?

Comment: @VonC I don't have Git installed in my PC. I don't know what happens while installing TortoiseHG, it should not install Git too. I do have EGit, which come with Eclipse, which cannot affect TortoiseHG.

Comment: @MinhasKamal OK, so no local git needed here. Can you check if your current TortoiseHG-hggit would work better with python 2.7.x instead of python 3.x?

Comment: @VonC How should I do that? Do you mean about the python installed in my PC? It is "Python 2.7.9rc1".

Comment: @MinhasKamal 2.7 should be fine. Maybe the reverse could be tested, installing python 3.3? I am just searching what factor would cause such an error message.

Comment: @MinhasKamal Also, just for test, what would happen if you were to rename your jar file in myfile.jar.txt, and then push it?

Comment: @VonC I renamed \*.jar with \*.txt extension, and I could not push. Then I renamed a \*.png file to \*.jar, but I could push. [This](https://github.com/MinhasKamal/test) is the repository.

Comment: @MinhasKamal so in png, it is ok, not in jar or txt?

Comment: @VonC I had a photo & I renamed it to *.jar, & it worked. So It is not file type rather file content that is causing the problem.

Comment: @VonC May be we could not figure out "how to solve the problem", but we were able to understand- "how we cannot solve it". Can't that be an answer too?

Comment: @MinhasKamal I agree. I have added an answer summarizing the conclusions so far.

Comment: I'm having the exact problem you have, but your solution does not apply to me. I'm trying to push the exact same files from my local repository to a new GitHub repository and get the error. If I push to the old repo, no problem and if I make a new local repository, no problem, but I need to push existing commits to the new repo. It must be something with my local .hg folder.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus The accepted answer does not give any solution, it simply addresses probable cause of the problem. If your are a fan of TortoiseHG, like me, but want to push in GitHub, then believe me, you are going to love [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). I tried TortoiseGit, EGit, & GitGui; but SourceTree is the closest I got to TortoiseHG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, after many comments, it seems the *content* of some binary file types (like- **.jar*, **.mp3* etc. but not **.png*) are problematic:

- not file size (although it the file was [really large](https://help.github.com/articles/conditions-for-large-files/), that would be an issue too, but it is not here)
- not its extension (the OP adds "I had a photo and I renamed it to `*.jar`, and it worked")

To keep a similar end-user experience, a test would be to install a **[TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)**, and see if a git push would work in a classic git clone repo.

Comment: I also tried with other *.jar files, and it did not work. I tried also with *.mp3 file (a song), it did not work either. :(

Comment: @MinhasKamal so a binary content seems to be systematically an issue.

Comment: Exactly. But not for image.

Comment: @MinhasKamal I don't know Mercurial enough but I suspect some encoding issue which might affect the content of those file during transfer.

Comment: @MinhasKamal At this point, I would test cloning the repo with git (instead of hggit) elsewhere on your computer, add those problematic files, commit and see if the push works that way.

Comment: Yes, like- `null` or something.

Comment: @MinhasKamal I have added a link to TortoiseGit, if you want to keep a similar GUI as TortoiseHg.

Comment: So, It seems like a TortoiseHG's hg-git extension issue, for certain types of binary files. There is also a slight possibility for GitHub issue too. I have changed your answer a bit, please verify if it is right.

Comment: @MinhasKamal Thank you for the edit: the answer is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

- I can't see *any* pushes to `MinhasKamal/MVCPracticeWork`: [This repository is empty.](https://github.com/MinhasKamal/MVCPracticeWork)
- You can automate pushing process (no handwork, no timeouts, no input errors) using [[auth] section](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) in .hgrc of this repo (define username and password in it)
- At least some initial test-pushes will be better to perform in pure CLI (more informative and readable output)

Comment: You cannot see any push cause- I could not. I tested push in repository- https://github.com/MinhasKamal/test. I was also able to push in repository- https://github.com/MinhasKamal/Egami a few minutes ago. So, there should not be any problem in version. Thanks a lot for your response. :)

Comment: @MinhasKamal - with `hg push -v --debug` you can see **a lot of** useful (?) data

Comment: Where should I write this (hg push -v --debug) command in TortoiseHG?

Comment: @MinhasKamal - out of ideas. I said about command-line and resolving your *real problem*

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with Github if you trying to add a super large file into any repo. Even though i don't know if that's your problem.

I had a change to commit with both HG and Git on my Mac and try to push it to github. Git shown me the file is too large message when I ran `git push` but HG only shown me push failed.

If your .jar or any of the file you added cause the problem, you can check if the file size excess the [limit (from github)](https://help.github.com/articles/conditions-for-large-files) and [this one](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that link was really informative. But my *\*.jar* file sized less than 500kb.

Comment: Sorry that's not helpful. Maybe that's some other reason? Hope you find answer asap

Answer (score 2):

This problem only occurs when you use the HTTPS protocol. If you use SSH instead (which is awkward, but nevertheless possible on Windows) the push will succeed.

See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2017-March/050304.html for more info. I suggest reading the whole thread, which is only six messages.